# Countif formula with multiple criteria and a date range

Tags: excel

I have a spreadsheet where I am counting the number of occurrences where the words below occur during a date range: “Not Interested,  Career Link, OVR, VBA, No Show”. All these are found in the same column, on Referrals" worksheet. I am trying to count the number of times that there is value in a cell other than the above. Is that possible?
Below is an example of the formula that I am currently using to count :

```
=COUNTIFS(Referrals!$K$2:$K$306,"VBA",Referrals!$A$2:$A$306,"<11/1/15")
```

Referrals refer to the "Referrals" worksheet. "VBA" is located on Referrals worksheet, Column K.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formula below counts the cells that do NOT contain the values “Not Interested, Career Link, OVR, VBA, No Show”

```
=COUNTIFS($K:$K,"<>Not Interested",$K:$K,"<>Career Link",$K:$K,"<>OVR",$K:$K,"<>VBA",$K:$K,"<>No Show",$A:$A,"<11/1/15")
```

Regards, Miguel

Comment: Miguel. It worked as expected, after I added the appropriate worksheet name. I added a larger date range to the formula & received an error message stating #VALUE. I know I probably missed punctuation, some where, but I don't know where. Here is the full formula:     =COUNTIFS(Referrals!$K$2:$K$306,"<>Not interested",Referrals!$K$2:$K$306,"<>CareerLink",Referrals!$K$2:$K$306,"<>OVR",Referrals!$K$2:$K$306,"<>VBA",Referrals!$K$2:$K$325,"No Show",Referrals!$A$2:$A$306,"<11/1/16",Referrals!$A2:A$325,">=11/30/16")  I have been banging my head against the wall trying to find it.

Comment: @FrankM your ranges need to be the same size.  Half way through you change from 2:306 to 2:325.  It is okay to use full column references `K:K` and `A:A`

Comment: @ScottCraner Thank you for showing me what I did wrong. It works exactly as expected.